# How can I implement "Drag" option in Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I trying to develop a game for iPhone by using Cocos2d. I need 'DRAG' option in Cocos2d. Is it possible to implement drag option in Cocos2d ?

Comment: I'm guessing yes, it is, using standard Cocoa Touch touch-handling code.  However, you need to provide more details as to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its done well:

```
-(BOOL)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    CGPoint convertedLocation = [[Director sharedDirector] convertCoordinate:location];
        //start ur logical code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To drag you can simply set the sprite's center to the location of the current touch coordinates.

[See the Apple Dev Sample: MoveMe](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MoveMe/Introduction/Intro.html) I think this will help.

Are you trying to create a pathfinding game like Flight Control or Harbor Master? Please explain with more detail what you are trying to achieve.